# Native Android development vs web mobile development

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, foursquare

I have to develop as soon as posible an appication (for android) similar to foursquare, I need to store some details in the phone and retrieve some other data from a web service. I can develop with phonegap or like a native app. What option do you recomend? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each one?

Comment: In this link there are a comparision table: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AsTInFQpmXDNdEdJU0ZNNGx3dDA3aXAxV3lXYWhXVHc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For *as soon as possible*, choose the platform you're more familiar with. Native development is in Java, Phonegap is in JavaScript and HTML. If you don't know either, hire someone who does - that'll be much faster that learning from scratch. Probably cheaper, too.

Comment: Java, HTML, JS are NOT part of Native development.

Comment: When the OP says the choice is "native vs. Phonegap", "native" means "the default platform for Android", not "native code as opposed to managed". That means Java. And I never claimed that HTML/JS was native, on the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to develop an app similar to foursquare you need to **develop a native** app. 
In fact I believe that you'll need to integrate the app with the use of the GPS and maps... this is not simple but this features are well documented.

Good luck :)

Comment: PhoneGap has APIs for integrating with the GPS and Google Maps API works fine for the mapping, AFAIK